# should you parboil boneless beef ribs?

Tags: flavor

I'm cooking beef ribs and I am trying to cook oriental ribs and I want to cut the cooking time in half.

Comment: Isn't "boneless beef ribs" an oxymoron?

Comment: @Cindy Nope: see "country style pork ribs" for another example. (There's no explaining the English language, or marketing-speak.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom I meant that 'tongue-in-cheek'. And I agree with you. Here we can get both bone-in and boneless country style pork ribs.

Answer (score 1):

You can parboil them with an acid such as vinegar (a technique some use to cook pork ribs) which can reduce your time a bit, but probably not half, and they probably won't be as good as if you simply braised them. Plus, you're leaving some of the flavor in the water you use to boil them.

As [GdD notes](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/74533/293), a pressure cooker is your best bet to speed up the process. Sear your ribs in it, put in whatever flavoring you want, add your braising liquid, deglaze, and let any alcohol cook out if needed. Bring it to a boil and secure the lid. Turn the heat way down (if using electric, have another burner waiting on low and transfer the cooker). Listen to sounds of valves and boiling going on for 15 minutes. Off the heat, release the pressure using the valve (or run it under water in your sink), open it and there you go - nicely braised ribs.

So essentially, if you get a pressure cooker (they're not expensive these days and they are quite safe now), you cut your cooking time by way more than half.

Answer (score 0):

If you want tender ribs there's no substitute for time. Ribs are full of connective tissue, which makes them tough. Connective tissue breaks down in the presence of moisture and heat over time. The only way I know of to speed it up is to use a pressure cooker.